# Geofences not deleting?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My app allows people to create geofences at certain locations. It works fine, however i cannot seem to remove the geofences. 
Here is my code for removing all the geofences.

```
    public void removeAllGeofences(GeofenceControllerListener listener) {
    namedGeofencesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    for (NamedGeofence namedGeofence : namedGeofences) {
        namedGeofencesToRemove.add(namedGeofence);
    }
    this.listener = listener;

    connectWithCallbacks(connectionRemoveListener);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, and the geofences remain unless i reboot my phone.
Any help or explanation as to how geofences work would really help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping geofence monitoring when it is no longer needed or desired can help save battery power and CPU cycles on the device. You can stop [geofence monitoring](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) in the main activity used to `add` and `remove` geofences; removing a geofence stops it immediately. The API provides methods to remove geofences either by request IDs, or by removing geofences associated with a given [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

The following snippet removes geofences by PendingIntent, stopping all further notification when the device enters or exits previously added geofences:

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
mGoogleApiClient,
// This is the same pending intent that was used in addGeofences().
getGeofencePendingIntent()
).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
}
```

You can combine geofencing with other location-aware features, such as periodic location updates. For more information, see the other lessons in this class.

To `temporary disable` store geofence parameters somewhere in your app (e.g. in sqlite or Shared Preferences), then remove it from `GeofencingApi` and restore (re-enable) when needed via addGeofences.

Answer (score 0):

GeofencingApi is no more in use.
Use geofencingClient instead.
And so you can remove all the geofences in one function.

Edit:
This link provides the explanation to the currently used API (I copied the section of the 'delete geofences'):
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#StopGeofenceMonitoring

Comment: It would add a lot of value in your answer if you were to add how to achieve that!

Comment: I agree, why post an answer with no code example?